# MATLAB Coder precision

Tags: c, xcode, matlab, precision, matlab-deployment

How can I increase precision of variables by the Coder toolbox generated c source code?

Unfortunately I have a ill-conditioned problem.

Comment: Did you mean ill-conditioned problem?

Comment: double precision is the standard for all sorts of scientific computing.  If your problem is too ill-conditioned for a standard double-precision solver, then you need to fix your problem in the math world before you get to the computer world.

Comment: @Peter: maybe the OP has a numeric problem which is intrinsically hard and cannot resort to rounding because he looks for an exact solution. Happens in formal verification, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that unless you rely on an external library, you cannot work at higher precision than what `long double` allows. I'm not aware (but I could be wrong) of any ability to interface Coder to the [Multiple Precision Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446) types on native code.

I would suggest to start from the generated C source code and then use an arbitrary precision library such as [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/). It requires some extra effort on your part, though.